# Get the size/number of fields of a particular document in Firestore using flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Is there any way to get the size of a particular document in Firestore using flutter? I need the number of fields in a particular document.

I'm trying to get the total number of fields in a particular document , however i can retrieve the number of documents in a collection but not the number of fields in a document .

Comment: You can either do what's in @frankvanpuffelen answer OR you can keep track of the number of fields of each document in a separate document. e.g suppose you hhave a document with two fields: `document_1/name_field` and `document_1/age_field` then in a separate collection called `document_field_count` have a document `document_1/count: 2`

Comment: That sounds like a great alternative answer Jay. :)

Comment: Maybe you should post it as a formal answer @Jay

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen your answer is (obviously) correct and there can't be two accepted answers so I just added some additional info to your answer. Edit if needed.

Comment: @LouisC I added my info to franks answer. Upvote if like it.

Comment: Hey Jay. It is actually encouraged and correct to post an alternative solution. While OP can only *accept* one answer, acceptance is a relatively minor signal for the value of an answer.  Also see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300254/can-an-alternative-solution-be-an-answer

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Well then, I was going by this *"You may want to add additional information to an answer to reflect changes in a new software version, fix an incorrect point (without changing the meaning of the core explanation), or add your own simpler variant of the solution. This is great and it's encouraged if you have full editing privileges"* but I will undo my egregious error. :-)

Comment: lol.... it wasn't an egregious error Jay. You know me better than that. ;-)

Thanks for posting it as a separate answer, I upvoted!

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, you could keep track of the number of fields of each document in a separate document. Suppose a document has two fields

```
document_1
    name_field
    age_field
```

then in a separate collection we keep track of the number of fields, using the same document id:

```
document_field_count
   document_1
      count: 2
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in operation to get the number of fields of a Firestore document. You will have to read the document and count its number of fields in your application code, by counting the number of elements in the [`snapshot.data()` map](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentSnapshot/data.html).